# JWT token retuns empty even though the token was created in postman

Tags: php, json, api, jwt, token

I am building a small API with JWT, and after I create my token with client id key in the API after it is sent in by the client with his client id key, I try to get that token back, in postman after creating the token successfully but I get response  **access token not found** which was what I set as response if it can't find the token in a constant I created which is in constant.php, please what am I doing wrong, I have tried to edit the code on my source code but nothing. PLEASE if my post needs correction please an edit would be appreciated.

```
 api.php //where I generate my token and create_insert_new_delivery() is the function that checks the incoming parameter for adding a new delivery according to the API i am building

public function generateToken(){ //WORKS PERFECTLY, BUT WHEN I TRY TO GET THE TOKEN
    try {
    $client_id_key = $this->validateParameter('client_id_key', $this->param['client_id_key'], STRING);
    //$client_secret_key = $this->validateParameter('client_secret_key', $this->param['client_secret_key'], STRING);
    //client_secret_key should be commented out it is not used for validation for security purposes, only id key

    $stmt = $this->dbConn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `api_clients_properties` WHERE client_id = :client_id_key");
    $stmt->bindParam(":client_id_key", $client_id_key);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!is_array($user)){
        $this->returnResponse(API_NAME_REQUIRED, "Invalid Client Id Key");
    }

    if ($user['property_status'] == "not verified"){
       $this->returnResponse(API_NAME_REQUIRED, "Property not verified, please contact admin, to verify it");   
    }

    $payload = [
       'iat' => time(),
       'iss' => 'localhost',
       'exp' => time() + (60),
       'userId' => $user['id']
    ];

    $token = JWT::encode($payload, SECRETE_KEY);

    $data = ['token' => $token];
    $this->returnResponse(SUCCESS_RESPONSE, $data);
} catch (Exception $e){
    $this->throwError(JWT_PROCESSING_ERROR, $e->getMessage());
}
}


public function create_insert_new_delivery(){
$c_payment_type = $this->validateParameter('payment_type', $this->param['payment_type'], STRING, true);

$c_date_of_delivery = $this->validateParameter('date_of_delivery', $this->param['date_of_delivery'], STRING, true);

$c_country_from = $this->validateParameter('country_from', $this->param['country_from'], STRING, true);
}

try {
      echo $token = $this->getBearerToken(); //Trying to get this token out, but its empty what am i doing wrong.



  } catch (Exception $e){
      $this->throwError(ACCESS_TOKEN_ERRORS, $e->getMessage()); //THIS "ACCESS_TOKEN_ERRORS" gives undefined token 
  }

}



 //constants.php the constant to serve errors
   /*Server Errors*/
define('JWT_PROCESSING_ERROR',                 300);  
define('AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NOT_FOUND',       301);
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_ERRORS',                 302);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people that might have the issue in the future, make sure the space between your Authorization value which is Bearer is accurate, only one space between them like this **Bearer YOUR.TOKEN.HERE** [image: Your Headers like that] you can echo your token, out like I did in my question and you will get the required token.